# Permissions to transfer SQL Server database ownership to sa

Tags: sql-server, continuous-integration

I'm struggling with the following conundrum when setting up a CI build process with SQL Server.

The databases need to be created by the CI agent. I prefer not to have that agent use the "sa" login for obvious reasons. So I created a specific user with dbcreator server role (for database creation) and securityadmin role (so I can script that as well).

The idea was to subsequently transfer database ownership to sa using

```
exec sp_changedbowner sa
```

However that gives the following error:

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Cannot find the principal 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

So, what permissions will my build agent user need to transfer db ownership?

Comment: You query syntax is wrong, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178630(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: The query syntax is not wrong, is just a shorthand for `exec sp_changedbowner  @loginame = 'sa'` (which gives the same error); verified because the same line works when logged in as 'sa'.